# Where does packer store the private key?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-ami, packer, ec2-ami

From ubuntu shell I ran below command, to talk to aws platform, to customise amazon ami(`ami-9abea4fb`):

```
$ packer build -debug template.packer 
Debug mode enabled. Builds will not be parallelized.
amazon-ebs output will be in this color.

==> amazon-ebs: Prevalidating AMI Name...
==> amazon-ebs: Pausing after run of step 'StepPreValidate'. Press enter to continue. 
==> amazon-ebs: Inspecting the source AMI...
==> amazon-ebs: Pausing after run of step 'StepSourceAMIInfo'. Press enter to continue. 
==> amazon-ebs: Creating temporary keypair: packer 5dfe9f3b-9cc2-cbfa-7349-5c8ef50c64d5
    amazon-ebs: Saving key for debug purposes: ec2_amazon-ebs.pem
==> amazon-ebs: Pausing after run of step 'StepKeyPair'. Press enter to continue.
```

where `template.packer` is:

```
{
    "builders": [
        {
            "type": "amazon-ebs",
            "region": "us-west-2",
            "source_ami": "ami-9abea4fb",
            "instance_type": "t2.micro",
            "ssh_username": "ubuntu",
            "ami_name": "MiddleTier-{{isotime | clean_ami_name}}",
            "ami_description": "Amazon AMI customised",
            "tags": {
                "role": "MiddleTier"
            },
            "run_tags":{
                "role": "buildSystem"
            }
        }
    ],
    "provisioners": [

    ],
    "post-processors":[

    ]
}
```

and my understanding is, AWS has created a private key(`ec2_amazon-ebs.pem`) for packer to talk to EC2 instance in passwordless way, as mentioned in above steps.

But I do not see packer copying the private key(`ec2_amazon-ebs.pem`) in my laptop(as `~/.ssh/ec2_amazon-ebs.pem`)

How does packer talk to EC2? without copying as `~/.ssh/ec2_amazon-ebs.pem` in my laptop

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unless Packer is given a private SSH with the `ssh_private_key_file` Packer creates an ephemeral that is only kept in memory while Packer is running.

When you run with the `-debug` flag this ephemeral key is saved into the current working directory. This is to enable you to troubleshoot the build by manually SSH'ing into the instance.

Comment: I don't see ephemeral key in same directory as template file. I verified

Comment: Sorry it's in the current working directory. See https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-ebs.html#accessing-the-instance-to-debug

Comment: My current working directory is same as directory with  template file..  let me verify again

Comment: Thats handy to know.  Only problem I have with debug is I'd like it to automatically continue until an error is reached, since the build takes a while with yum update to get to the point of failure, thats when I'd like to probe the instance.  Is that also possible with these methods?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to connect to the instance is to set following 2 properties.

```
ssh_keypair_name      # provide the aws keypair name which already exists. 
ssh_private_key_file  # provide the path to private key associated with above keypair. ~ resolves to current user's home directory.
```

Also set the `associate_public_ip_address` if public IP is not allocated to the instance (or else you will have to use bastion host to ssh into the machine).

This should allow you to ssh as follows:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/private_key.pem ec2-user@<InstancePublicIP>
```

Change the file name as per the actual private key path. Also change the user name as per the OS (eg. ubuntu for ubuntu based machine instead of ec2-user)

You can either use the breakpoint provisioner to pause the packer execution like this:

```
provisioner "breakpoint" {
    disable = true
    note    = "this is a breakpoint"
}
```

or you can pause the packer execution on error something like this.

```
packer build -on-error=ask .
```

This will allow you to ssh into the instance to verify the script while packer is paused for input.

Debug flag as follows

```
packer build -debug .
```

will also allow you to pause the packer build.

Once the build is paused use the above ssh command to connect to the instance.